Can I connect two AC junction boxes with romex?
I am relocating two hidden junction boxes into the attic. I plan on cutting the EMT pipe, pulling it he wire up from the old boxes and then joining the wires in a junction box.
Is it ok to attach a junction box on each pipe and connect the two with romex? Then ground the romex to the boxes correctly. Currently the pipe has just two AC wires and the metal boxes are grounded back to the box after testing them. Or should I use a length of MC armor wire to connect the two? Is either method acceptable? Thank you.


Some jurisdictions require conduit for virtually everything -- do you live in one of those?

No I don’t need to use conduit. And one person tell me that I should keep the system in tact by using MC armor vs Romex. Not sure if there is fact behind that or not.

Romex not in walls usually needs to be protected below eight feet from the floor.  To stop people from hanging on it or stepping/tripping over it.

There isn’t a permanent ladder or stairs and these boxes would be more than 6ft away from the entrance. So protected wire isn’t my concern. I just want to make sure by addding romex into the circuit I don’t disrupt the integrity of the circuit.

If Romex was legal in your area, why on earth would the last guy use EMT?  How would you splice from what's in the conduit now to the Romex? Where would that splice happen and how would the individual wires in the conduit be protected from the conduit cut to the new junction box?  Can you chase those individual wires down to the next accessible J-box and replace the whole run with Romex (which in part might be inside the old conduit)?

I can’t answer for the last 75yrs of renovations and additions to the house. Every time I start a project I ask the same question, why on earth would they…put plaster over junction boxes 15yrs ago, leave open plumbing venting in the walls, etc. All I can tell you is that there is AC running through pipe, older NM and Romex running throughout the house.
I have excess wire that I cannot a pipe, pull wire to ensure no damaged
